# Are bluebird promises blocking in nature

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I may be a bit new to understand the underlying functioning of promises esp bluebird. What i am trying to accomplish is an API server that processes bulk write of 250K+ rows into a database. It takes around 30s to complete the request. I want the API server to return ok or error based on the success of the bulk write. When i don't use promises i don't get an opportunity to bubble up the error because the request is not waiting for the bulk write to complete. However, if I use promise the error and success works properly. But the server becomes unresponsive till the action is complete. In nutshell, using the promise library to handle the bulk write blocks the API server.

```
function chunk(arr, chunkSize) {
  var R = [];

  for (var i=0,len=arr.length; i<len; i+=chunkSize)
    {
        R.push(arr.slice(i,i+chunkSize));
    }
  return promise.resolve(R);
}


exports.add = function(req, res) {
var PO_STD_LT_TIME = 90; //DAYS
    Parts.sync()
        .then(function() {
            return Parts.destroy({
                where: {}
            });
        })
        .then(function() {
            var workbook = XLSX.readFileSync(__dirname + '/dbo_tblCPLParts_.xlsx');
            var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
            var JSON_S = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);

            var size = 40000;
            chunk(JSON_S, size).then(function(JSON_Small) {
                promise.each(JSON_Small, function (JSON_small_){
                    Parts.bulkCreate(JSON_small_)
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        res.json(500, {
                            Error: "Error : " + err
                        });
                    })

                }).finally(ext_fns.handleResult(res,200))
            })
            })

}
```

What is the best way to handle this? Am I using the promise the right way?

Comment: all js is blocking (except setTimeout/interval). only the host can provide the opportunity to take a break

Comment: Presumably the task always took 30s to complete, but before promisifying, you were unaware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're invoking synchronous behavior along the way. The culprit is

```
var workbook = XLSX.readFileSync(__dirname + '/dbo_tblCPLParts_.xlsx');
```

You should instead use the XLSX equivalent of [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback), which is asynchronous. Alternatively, since you're using bluebird, you can use [`promisifyAll`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisepromisifyallobject-target--object-options---object) on the `XLSX` module:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(/* the XLSX module */)
```

which will allow you to treat all the XLSX modules as promises.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. unfortunately, the XLSX module internally uses fs.readfileSync. I tried converting it but it is not working. I guess i need to look into child process and other parallel processing stuff.

Comment: @UmaMaheshwaraa are there any async versions of the xlsx module?

Comment: found one but its a different library. need to see whether it works for my purpose.

Comment: @UmaMaheshwaraa were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: no still banging my head.unfortunately there is no xlsx library that uses promises. I checked the internals of that library and it uses fs.readfileSync. So I am stuck. Do you know of any other implementation for long tasks.. Emitting progress with child worker.

Comment: @UmaMaheshwaraa you don't need promises; you just need something asynchronous (aka with a callback). Does [xlsx-async](https://github.com/JoseBarrios/async-xlsx) work?

Comment: nope xlsx-async is not a drop in replacement for xlsx. It seems to not work at this moment.

Comment: @UmaMaheshwaraa can you roll your own based on the xlsx code? You really only need to make sure it uses asynchronous functions throughout (it might be an easy fix).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a protip.

In io.js (NodeJS) recently a synchronous io flag was added. Fetch the most recent version and run it with `--trace-sync-io`. It wil figure out all your synchronous blocking issues - I suspect they are not promises related.

As for bluebird - it is not blocking.